# How to archieve the same effect as word-break on absolute positioned text?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm looking for a method to archieve the same as `overflow-wrap: break-word;` for absolute positioned text.

Here a demo of the issue:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 1px dashed red 
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* How to archive the same effect as following */
  /* overflow-wrap: break-word; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">loremipsumdoloremelit</span>
</div>
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: can someone upvote de question ? :)) the code was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `word-break: break-word` do what you'd like? It seems to.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 1px dashed red
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">loremipsumdoloremelit</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property

```
word-break:break-all;
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 1px dashed red 
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* How to archive the same effect as following */
   /*overflow-wrap: break-word; */
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">loremipsumdoloremelit</span>
</div>
```